# How to compare last 3 char of a input string in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a text box which gets the link for mp3 files,

Ex: http://www.woo55.com/play/6812/01-till-the-world-ends--(www-songslover-com)-mp3

if the user is entering the above link how can I get the last 3 letters to compare it to find whether it ends with mp3. Can I do it in client side, or is it only possible to do it in server side, I want to do this in asp.net website, my backend is c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the link to a string and you can check like this.

```
        if(link.ToLower().EndsWith("mp3"))
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<yourString>.EndsWith("mp3")` will return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this either client side or server side. To do it with Javascript (client side) you could simply concatenate the last three characters of the string and see if it equals what you're looking for:

```
var link = "http://www.woo55.com/play/6812/01-till-the-world-ends--(www-songslover-com)-mp3";
var lastThreeChars = link.charAt(link.length-3) + link.charAt(link.length-2) + link.charAt(link.length-1);
if(lastThreeChars == "mp3") //do something
```